# Prefer multiple Solr applications or single application multicore setup?

Tags: solr

What are the pros and cons of having multiple Solr applications for completely different searches comparing to having a single Solr application but have different searches setup as separate cores?

What is the Solr's preferred method? Is having a single Solr application with multicore setup (for various search indexes) is always a right way?

Answer (score 2):

There is no preferred method. It depends on what you are trying to solve. So by nature, can handle multiple cores on the single Solr instance or can have cores across Solr application servers , can handle the collection (in solrcloud).

Having said that, usually you go for 
1) Single core on a Solr instance if your data is fairly small - few million documents. 
2) You go  for multiple solr instances with a single core on each if you want to shard your data incase of billions of documents and want to get better indexing and query performance.
3) You go for multiple cores on single or multiple solr instances if you have multitenancy separating, example a core for each customer or a for catalog another core for skus.

It depends on your use case, the volume of data and query response times etc.